# Use Text From WPF Menu Item

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, serial-port

I have a menu which lists the current available com ports on the computer. What I want is to get the text of the of the menu item. i.e. if I select `COM7` it will store `COM7` into a string. Here is the `XAML` code for the menu:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="Menu_Port" Header="Port">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Then the code to get the com ports:

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

and the code to add it to the menu:

```
Menu_Port.ItemsSource = ports;
```

It does the menu correctly, I just need to get the data. All I have managed to do is get the first item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a list of `string` to the menu, you need to create a `MenuItem` for each port, and register a click event for that item and then add it to the main menu. Change your code behind to this:

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

foreach (string port in ports)
{
   MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem { Header = port };
   menuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Menu_Port_Click);

   Menu_Port.Items.Add(menuItem);
}
```

And then add an event handler method to get the text from the menu item (i.e. the port):

```
private void Menu_Port_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string selectedPort = ((MenuItem)sender).Header.ToString();

   // Alternatively, if you want to maintain a list of selected ports, you can do something like this:
   MenuItem selectedMenu = ((MenuItem)sender);

   if (selectedMenu.IsChecked)
   {
      // In this case "allSelectedPorts" is a global string list.
      allSelectedPorts.Add(selectedMenu.Header.ToString());
   }
   else
   {
      allSelectedPorts.Remove(selectedMenu.Header.ToString());
   }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want only one menu item selected at a time, you can do something like this:

```
 string selectedPort = string.Empty;

 private void Menu_Port_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     MenuItem selectedMenu = ((MenuItem)sender);

     Menu_Port.Items.Cast<MenuItem>().Where(
       menu => menu != selectedMenu).ToList().ForEach(item => item.IsChecked = false);

     if (selectedMenu.IsChecked)
     {
        selectedPort = selectedMenu.Header.ToString();
     }
     else
     {
        selectedPort = string.Empty;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried to put it in but I am getting an error on this line in your code: (MenuItem)menu.Items.Cast<MenuItem>().Single(x => x.Name=="Menu_Port");
It says that menu (after the first (MenuItem)) does not exist in this context.

Comment: Oh sorry I totally spaced on that. That is the `ContextMenu` that the `MenuItem` is in. Just give it a name.

Comment: @NickFalconer Updated my answer. Give it another shot.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One more question. What is the simplest way of have it deselect the previous selection when another is chosen. i.e. if I choose COM8 it checks it, Then if I select COM3 I want it to Check that one and uncheck COM8. Thanks

Comment: @NickFalconer see my update. This will let you have only one selected menu at a time.